# IBM Worklight 6.0 - Trouble adding the Worklight file entries option

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-studio

I am trying to install Worklight 6 following [these instructions](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wrklight/v6r0m0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.worklight.help.doc/devenv/t_installing_ibm_worklight_studi.html) on the IBM website.

Steps 1 - 10 complete (as far as I can tell) successfully. The instructions then say

> Before you run Worklight Studio, determine whether you must run extra
>   post-installation tasks. Important: After you finish installing IBM
>   Worklight Developer Edition, when you restart Eclipse, click **Window >
>   Open perspective > Other, and select Design** in the Open Perspective
>   window. If you do not select the Design perspective, you cannot see
>   the Worklight entries when you click File > New. When you click File >
>   New after Design is selected, you can see the Worklight entries.

I do not see the entry for Design in the Open Perspective window. The installation history tells me that Worklight is installed so I assume I should be able to complete the **What to do next steps** but I can't.

Eclipse 4.2.2
IBM 1.7 JDK
Worklight 6
Ubuntu 12.04

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you choose to install all 3 options during the installation? Namely:

- IBM Worklight Studio
- IBM jQuery Mobile Tools
- IBM Dojo Mobile tools

In any case, there is another way to add the Worklight options (it will add it to both the File >> New... menu and the right-click context menu >> New...):

1. Window >> Customize Perspective... >> Shortcuts
2. In the Shortcuts Categories section on the left side scroll all the way to the bottom and tick the "Worklight" checkbox
3. Press OK

Even w/out doing the above, you always have the Worklight icon in the top toolbar which hold the same functionality.

Personally I don't like using the File menu for that. I find myself using either the Worklight icon in the top toolbar or the right-click context menu (less restrictive as you can get to it from anywhere you right-click while in Eclipse).

Comment: All three are installed.  

Sadly there is no Worklight option to select in the Shortcuts Categories in your step 2. Something must be messed up.

Comment: Is the Worklight icon in the top toolbar even available...?

Comment: I suggest a new eclipse + workspace and another attempt to install Worklight.

Comment: The Worklight icon is not available in the top tool bar. I will try another workspace and report back.

Comment: Problem fixed. I can now see the Worklight menus and icons. Here's what I had to do: Starting with a fresh install of Eclipse I restarted the IDE as an admin user. I then installed Worklight. I changed the owner of the workspace back to my regular user (since the admin user took ownership of the Worklight files that were installed) and restarted. I can still see the icons and menus. :) Not sure why I couldn't install Worklight as a regular user as I have done with other items for Eclipse. Perhaps a note in the troubleshooting or installation instructions would help others? Thanks for the help!